# Git: Checkout specific commit and get corresponding submodule version

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to checkout a specific past commit of a git repository, let's say its hash is `'a1bc2def3'`:

```
git checkout a1bc2def3
```

The git repository makes heavy use of submodules. As their latest version is incompatible with the old commit, I want to checkout the latest commit of each submodule at the time of the local commit `'a1bc2def3'`.

Do you know if there is a way to achieve that?

Comment: `git branch mybranch a1bc2def3`

Comment: @RPM please create an answer from your comment

Comment: @muffel The comment is not an answer, and not helpful for the asker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is to run

```
git submodule update
```

after your `checkout` operation in the superproject.

Your subprojects (submodules) will then be checked out to the commit they were at when your superproject commit was created (they one that you have just check out with e.g. `git checkout a1bc2def3`).